# MySQL call for additional filtering for certain rows, only if another table is populated

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

**Two clarifications:**

- I'm going to actually be doing pagination with this, so ideally it can be one SQL statement...
- If this helps, what I'm trying to do is: Get all content for user, BUT if content item has criteria in content_criteria table, check that user also has criteria in users_criteria table, OTHERWISE, content is valid for user

So this might be hard to explain. Let's start with the main tables:

**content:**

```
| contentIdNum | contentStr | programIdNum |
```

A piece of content (unlike users) can only be associated with one program. 
A typical record would be like this. Both are associated with a program with id of 1.

```
| 1 | Zelda | 1 |
| 2 | Mario | 1 |
```

**content_criteria:**

```
| contentIdNum | criteriaIdNum |
```

A typical record would be like this: (this basically a table that associates content with criteria. Not all content is associated with criteria.)

```
| 1 | 5 |
```

** user_criteria: **

```
| userIdNum | criteriaIdNum |
```

A typical record would be like this: (this basically a table that associates users with criteria. Not all content is associated with criteria.) Note that userIdNum 1 has the same criteria as contentIdNum 1

```
| 1 | 5 |
```

** program_users: **

```
| userIdNum | criteriaIdNum |
```

A typical record would be like this (both user 1 and 2 are associated with program 1)

```
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
```

So here's what I need to do:

- Create a MySQL call that returns all pieces of content a user has access to
- By default, a user has access to all content associated with the programs he is assigned to
- If a piece of content has criteria associated with it in the content_criteria table, ONLY users with that corresponding criteria in the user_criteria table have access to that content
- For example, if I pass in userIdNum 1, I should get both pieces of content
- If I pass in userIdNum of 2, I should only get one piece of content (the one with contentIdNum of 2)

Obviously selecting content that matches a user's programs is easy (below is what I have). I'm trying to figure out an easy way to filter the content - can I do it in one go, or do I have to do a secondary pass and loop through the content via PHP?

```
SELECT DISTINCT (c.contentIdNum), c.*
FROM content c , program_users pu 
WHERE 1=1 
AND pu.userIdNum = 2 AND pu.programIdNum = c.programIdNum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it thanks to UNIONs. The first part of the UNION gets all content that does NOT have a criteria to filter by. The second part of the UNION gets all content with a criteria to filter by, if the user has that criteria.

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM    content           c , 
        program_users     pu 
WHERE   pu.userIdNum      = 1
AND     pu.programIdNum   = c.programIdNum
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM content_criteria cc
    WHERE cc.contentIdNum = c.contentIdNum
)
UNION 
SELECT  c.*
FROM content_criteria cc, users_criteria uc, content c
WHERE cc.contentIdNum = c.contentIdNum
AND cc.criteriaIdNum = uc.criteriaIdNum
AND uc.userIdNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  c.*
FROM    content           c , 
        program_users     pu , 
        content_criteria  cc, 
        user_criteria     uc
WHERE   pu.userIdNum      = 2 
AND     pu.programIdNum   = c.programIdNum
and     cc.contentIdNum   = c.contentIdNum
and     uc.criteriaIdNum  = cc.criteriaIdNum
and     uc.userIdNum      = pu.userIdNum
```

should do the trick.

"distinct" is a really good way of hiding bugs - especially while you're still trying to work out what your query should look like.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately this won't do the trick. When I pass in 2, I get no results where I should get 1, because 2 does not have any data in the user_criteria table. If I pass in 1, I only get 1 item where I should get two.